# Why won't my stylesheet link to the index?

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, my stylesheet won't link to the index file. I've been working at this for a while now and I can't sort out the issue. The syntax looks correct.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
This is a test.
</body>

</head>
```

It works in the snippet, but not in my browser. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. 
 This is a picture of my folder structure.
[image]

Comment: Can we see the folder structure. A picture would be nice

Comment: @EQuimper Picture added. It if it helps to know, I'm using Atom.

Comment: But it is working here on the Code snippet you added

Comment: Take a look in your developer console on chrome and see if there are any 404 errors in the console. If there are, you can see from that the exact path it's trying to find the stylesheet in.

Comment: Try to use different browser. Or press ctrl + f5 if you're using windows.

Comment: I tried every suggestion and nothing worked. Same problem in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I fixed the error. I had the file declared as style/css instead of text/css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a test</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Try Using this it always helps to break it down to the very minimum. and its not style/css :P

Comment: Yeah, style/css was the problem. Thanks!